# Preg_replace plus and dots in gmail

Tags: php, regex, email

spammers driving me crazy. Don't know how Google allows infinite email aliases just by adding a dot or a plus. So I need to kind of sanitize emails like these:

- john.brian@gmail.com
- henix..mail+@gmail.com
- sar+ah+.black+.+@gmail.com

to this:

- johnbrian@gmail.com
- henixmail@gmail.com
- sarahblack@gmail.com

The regular expression that works is this:
`(?:\.|\+.*)(?=.*?@gmail\.com)`

My email function is $mail['email'], so how do I match dots and plus in this function if found then remove them and clean them up?

What i've found by now...
Works but don't know how to if this then that

```
preg_match( '/@gmail\.com$/', $mail['email']
preg_replace('^(?:\.|\+.*)(?=.*?@gmail\.com)$',  $mail['email'] );
```

Comment: I don't think you want to just strip all plus signs. GMail's plus support is an optional plus sign followed by an arbitrary string. E.g., `foo+bar@gmail.com` is the same as `foo@gmail.com` -- it is _not_ the same as `foobar@gmail.com`

Comment: Thanks didnt know that. I'll remove the + by now

Comment: It's a super handy feature BTW -- I use it every time I order something online, using a plus-address based on the site I'm visiting, like alex+stackoverflow@gmail.com. Then if I ever get spammed to that address, I know who leaked it, and I can block just that one variant. I've lost count of how many data breaches I've identified this way. <stares at LinkedIn>

Comment: dude that's genious, never thought about that. I always wondered how some fake companies got my email and that's a good solution to catch them. Now I hope G doesn't reverse that feature...how quick I changed my mind on this lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern in anchored, so using `^(?:\.|\+.*)(?=.*?@gmail\.com)$` will not find separate matches.

Also the `+.*` could match more than only the plus sign, removing more than expected.

You could match either dot or a plus sign using a character class `[.+]` and assert gmail.com to the right using a positive lookahead, matching only non whitspace chars except an @ until you encounter the first occurrence of @

See the matches on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4RIrbL/1).

For example:

```
$pattern = "/[.+](?=[^\s@]*@gmail\.com)/";

$mail = ["email" => "sar+ah+.black+.+@gmail.com"];
$mail['email'] = preg_replace($pattern, '',  $mail['email'] );

print_r($mail['email']);
```

Output

```
sarahblack@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want your match to work, you can add to @The fourth bird answer :

```
preg_replace($pattern, '',  $mail['email'] ,-1,$changes);
if ($changes>0) {
    echo "Mail changed";
}
```

Comment: Nice addon for user recognizing he has been busted. Thanks!!

Comment: @cortexAD I'm not as good in regex as you but it was too bad to erase all my contribution lol.